# Uncaught TypeError: elements[i].attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('data-table');
    var elements = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].on("ifChanged", handle_company_state(elements[i].attr('id')));
     }
}

function handle_company_state(element_id) {
    //....
}
```

When I'm trying to run it I' getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: elements[i].attr is not a function

Why?

Comment: Are you using jQuery ? The .on() and .attr() methods must be applied to jQuery objects

Comment: $(elements[i]).attr(... etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use [getattribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) method instead `.attr` and [addEventListener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) instead `.on`. And [you might not need jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

```
function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('data-table');
    var elements = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener("ifChanged", handle_company_state(elements[i].getAttribute('id')));
    }
 }
function handle_company_state(element_id) {
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(elements[i]).attr()
```

`$.attr()` is jQuery method. The same fix applies for your `.on()` function

```
$(elements[i]).on("ifChanged", handle_company_state($(elements[i]).attr('id')));
```

And since you're using jQuery here.

You can *write less*.

```
var container = $('#data-table'),
    elements  = container.find('input'); // container is a jQuery object; thus, $.find() works as traversing method in the DOM. see http://api.jquery.com/find/

$(elements).on("ifChanged", function(){
    handle_company_state($(this).attr('id'))); // use `this` as reference to changed element.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: elements[i].on is not a function

Comment: @AdamAzad Why you think TS need jQiery? It obvious that him dont use it. Add to you answer, how he can add jquery lib, if you want you code worked for him.

Comment: @Darth, **1-** jQuery is tagged. **2-**, he's using `on()` and `.attr()` methods. These are my clues. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
function () {
    var elements = $("#data-table input");
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        $(elements[i]).on("ifChanged", handle_company_state($(elements[i]).attr('id')));
    }
}

function handle_company_state(element_id) {
    //....
}
```

Comment: You know that `document.getElementById('#_id_')` is 10 times faster than `$('#_id_')` ?

Comment: I also know it's not enough to affect the UX. It's a trade-off between simplicity and performance. I would rather stick with jQuery since it's much more flexible and makes the code cleaner.